# Excel macro transposition problem - 2 column list into columns based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have BOM's that is bill of materials in 2 column list, lots of them, and I am trying to convert them to multiple columns, that is product only once in first column, and all components in columns from 2 onwards.

currently product repeats itself in column 1 as many times as many components it contains, and I want it to look sort of pivot, but component numbers instead of values

[image]

I was trying to use this code, but it makes the same table in next sheet as origin.

```
Sub ExtractAssignedCells()
Dim ws As Worksheet, newSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet ' Set the source worksheet

Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add ' Add a new sheet

lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' Find the last row in column A on the source sheet

i = 1 ' Counter for row on the new sheet

For j = 1 To lastRow ' Iterate through each value in column 1

Dim valueCell As Range
Set valueCell = ws.Cells(j, 1) ' Set the current cell in column 1

Dim assignedCells As Range
Set assignedCells = ws.Cells(j, 2).Resize(WorksheetFunction.CountA(valueCell.EntireColumn) - 1) ' Set the assigned cells in column 2

newSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = valueCell.Value ' Put value in column A on the new sheet

assignedCells.Copy newSheet.Cells(i, 2) ' Copy the assigned cells to column B on the new sheet

i = i + 1 ' Move to the next row on the new sheet

Next j

MsgBox "Assigned cells extracted to a new sheet."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you also tagged Excel-Formula, here is an option using one:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=LET(u,UNIQUE(DROP(TOCOL(A:A,3),1)),VSTACK(HSTACK(A1,B1&" "&SEQUENCE(,MAX(COUNTIF(A:A,u)))),DROP(IFNA(REDUCE(0,u,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,HSTACK(y,TOROW(FILTER(B:B,A:A=y)))))),""),1)))
```

I guess, if one want to, this can probably be golfed down.

Comment: Thanks for You answer, unfortunately I got info First argument of Let function must be proper name

Comment: @GrzegorzSzwaczka, this answer requires ms365. Maybe that's why.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzwaczka I got the same error, but that was simply because the formula uses ',' as separator and a Dutch installation uses ';'. So check your localization.

Answer (score 3):

Use VBA I gather the data using a collection of collections to store the values and create an array of values from it.

```
Sub ExtractAssignedCells()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, newSheet As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet ' Set the source worksheet
    Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add ' Add a new sheet

    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = getAssignedCells(ws)
    
    newSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Data), UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
    
    MsgBox "Assigned cells extracted to a new sheet."
End Sub

Function getAssignedCells(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns("A:B").Value
    
    Dim ColumnCount As Long, r As Long
    Dim Items As Object: Set Items = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim Value As Variant
    For r = 2 To UBound(Data, 1)
        Key = Data(r, 1)
        Value = Data(r, 2)
        If Not Items.Exists(Key) Then
            Items.Add Key:=Key, Item:=New Collection
            Items(Key).Add Item:=Value
        Else
            Items(Key).Add Item:=Value
        End If
        If Items(Key).Count > ColumnCount Then ColumnCount = Items(Key).Count
    Next
    
    Dim Result As Variant
    ReDim Result(1 To Items.Count, 1 To ColumnCount + 1)
    Dim c As Long
    Dim r2 As Long
    For Each Key In Items.Keys
        r2 = r2 + 1
        Result(r2, 1) = Key
        For c = 1 To Items(Key).Count
            Value = Items(Key)(c)
            Result(r2, c + 1) = Value
        Next
    Next
    
    getAssignedCells = Result
End Function
```

Comment: Thank You for sparing time to write this to me. Works as charm

Answer (score 2):

Likewise, since you have tagged **`Excel-formula`**, here is an alternative.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A11</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(A$10:A10,$A$2:$A$6),0)),"")
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B11</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$B$6)-ROW($B$2)+1)/
($A11=$A$2:$A$6),COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

---

The above formula needs to filled down and filled right, also depending on ones Excel Version may need to hit the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

---

This task can be accomplished using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> as well, which will be the **`easiest approach`**. Available in <kbd>Windows</kbd> **`Excel 2010+`** and **`Excel 365`** <kbd>Windows or Mac</kbd>

[image]

---

- First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"component", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"item"}, {{"comp", each Text.Combine([component],","), type nullable text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "comp", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"comp.1", "comp.2", "comp.3"})
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---